# Can't track changes on a Rich Text Area field with Field History Tracking enabled

Tags: custom-field, history-tracking, richtextarea, field-history

I have a scenario, where I would like to track the changes on a Rich Text Area field.

**Step 1**

After enabling the field history tracking on the Opportunity(*that is my target object*), I check the history tracking option for the desired field, *as shown in the picture*:
[image]

**Step 2**

After editing the Rich Text Area field, 1 time, relatively to the value that was before(*1. Test 1*):
[image]

**Step 3**

I can see 2 entries at my field history tracking related list, but the trouble is that I cannot see any change tracked anyhwere:

[image]

**Resolution:**

Is this a bug or an intended behaviour? Either ways, as the Rich Text Area Field is available for selection on the Field History Tracking, one would expect that somehow this data should be trackable.

Answer (score 1):

This is an intended behavior. From the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=tracking_field_history.htm&type=5),

> Changes to fields with more than 255 characters are tracked as edited, and their old and new values are not recorded.

Here is a [workaround](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=906300000004BsmAAE) for this limitation - Uses a Workflow Rule / Trigger with additional field.

Answer (score 0):

This is a expected behavior. Few fields like RTA, Long text area, MSPL only allow to track changes in them. They don't actually track what are the  new and old values here.

You need to implement custom functionality to get the old and new values.